# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python

I'm getting a strange error from the Python interpreter when I run this code:

```
def make_map():
    map = [[Tile(0, 0) for col in range(MAP_WIDTH)] for row in range(MAP_HEIGHT)]

    for x in range(MAP_WIDTH):
        for y in range(MAP_HEIGHT):     
            map[x][y].tileType = round((libtcod.noise_perlin(noise2d,[y/MAP_WIDTH,x/MAP_HEIGHT])*100), 0)
```

It's returning this in the terminal:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is unsubscriptable
```

The traceback is also pointing to this function:

```
def render_all():
    global color_light_wall
    global color_light_ground

    #go through all tiles, and set their background color
    for y in range(MAP_HEIGHT):
        for x in range(MAP_WIDTH):
            tileType = map[x][y].tileType
            if tileType>30:
                libtcod.console_set_back(con, x, y, color_dark_wall, libtcod.BKGND_SET )
            else:
                libtcod.console_set_back(con, x, y, color_dark_ground, libtcod.BKGND_SET )

    #draw all objects in the list
    for object in objects:
        object.draw()

    #blit the contents of "con" to the root console
    libtcod.console_blit(con, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 0, 0)
```

I think they're both related to this line:  `tileType = map[x][y].tileType` but if somebody could shed some light on this, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks, Elliot Bonneville

EDIT: I forgot to include my Tile class code and the full traceback:

```
class Tile:
    #a tile of the map and its properties
    def __init__(self, tileType, blocked):
        self.tileType = tileType
        self.blocked = blocked
```

Traceback:

```
  File "kindred.py", line 123, in <module>
    render_all()
  File "kindred.py", line 64, in render_all
    tileType = map[x][y].tileType
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is unsubscriptable
```

Comment: Please provide a *full* traceback and not traceback snippets - they are totally not helpful

Comment: Well, obviously `map` contains "built-in functions or methods" instead of `Tile` objects. We can't tell you why or where it happens from the code you showed. Try `print repr(map)`, and post the output (or a snippet of the output if it's large).

Comment: The output is hundreds of lines of <__main__.Tile instance at 0x97572ac>. (I assume that's the location of the tile instance in memory?)

Comment: The code you've posted, as it stands, doesn't contain a definition of a function called `render_all`. It would be more helpful if you'd post actual functions from your code, rather than extracts from them!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. The second snippet of code I posted is that function -- I somehow didn't copy in the def line. Fixing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error mean that python try to get a variable name "map" in `tileType = map[x][y].tileType` but he don't find it any where so it fetch the build in function [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), which is unsubscriptable because it's a built-in function that explain the error message:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is unsubscriptable
```

What i will advise you is first to change your variable name from "map" to whatever to not shadow any built-in function, and second when you will change your variable name you should have a `NameError` error because your variable isn't defined so you should fix that.

Hope i get it right and hope this help :)

Comment: @Elliot: Glad i was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your make_map function doesn't fail for me when I provide definitions for `MAP_WIDTH`, `MAP_HEIGHT`, `noise2d` and `libtcod.noise_perlin`. (But -- though I'm sure this has nothing to do with the error you're getting -- you need to be accessing the array as `map[y][x]`, not `map[x][y]` since it's a list of rows, not of columns.

Of course Python has a `map` builtin function. Is the code you provided really literally what's in your code, or (e.g.) is `map` set up in one place and then used in another? Because if for some reason your `map` is out of scope when you start trying to reference `map[x][y].tileType` then you'll get the builtin function `map` instead, which will produce errors of the sort you list.

Incidentally, *because* Python has that builtin, it's probably bad style to call one of your variables `map` in the first place.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know Python already had a map function already built in. Let me check to see if what you suggested is the problem.

Comment: Funny enough, pointing out that I needed to access as map[y][x] solved a second problem that popped up when the first one was fixed. :) Upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You have a name clash and the build-in map() method is used here.

Answer (score 0):

As others have guessed, the `map` in `render_all` refers to the global built-in function [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map). The `map = ...` part in `make_map` merely creates a local variable, which dies when the function returns and isn't visible to any other function. Just `return map` at the end of `make_map` and store it somewhere `render_all` can access it, or (even better) pass it as parameter to `render_all`.

Note that generally shouldn't shadow built-in names, i.e. don't name anything `map` or `filter` or `any` or ...

Also, when iterating over a list or any other sequence (and you don't need to actually re-assign the objects stored in it), use:

```
for row in rows:
    for obj in rows:
        ... # use obj
```